# Combine two different select statements, one distinct the other not

Tags: sql

I have two selects which are required to filter data.  They are not complicated:

```
"SELECT * FROM StevesTable t WHERE "
"t.data1 = '%s' AND "
"t.data2 = to_date('%s','DD/MM/YYYY');",
strdata1,
dtDate.Format();
```

and

```
SELECT distinct data1 FROM anothertable ftt
join table1 tab on tab.somedata = ftt.somedata
where tab.somedata = 0
and tab.someotherdata = 1
```

I would like to combine these two as I need to filter the returned dataset from the first select statement by the returned field in the second (ie if a record returned in the first set does not have a data1 value which is contained in the second returned set it is invalid).

I tried to union and intersect the selects but you need the same number of columns returned and that cannot happen as these are completely different tables.  When I tried to simply merge them together I found it difficult as the second select statement is a distinct select whereas the first is not.

I was wondering whether I had missed a trick somewhere for combining these sorts of selects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a SQL sub-query:

```
SELECT * FROM StevesTable t 
WHERE t.data1 = '%s' 
AND t.data2 = to_date('%s','DD/MM/YYYY')
AND t.data1 in (select distinct data1 FROM anothertable ftt
    join table1 tab on tab.somedata = ftt.somedata
    where tab.somedata = 0
    and tab.someotherdata = 1)
```

There, you check that all records in the first select have a data1 value in the second set.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks very much, I am not able to up vote for your answer but I would if I could.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using an EXISTS condition:

```
SELECT * FROM StevesTable t 
WHERE t.data1 = '%s' AND 
      t.data2 = to_date('%s','DD/MM/YYYY') AND
      EXISTS (select null
              from anothertable ftt
              join table1 tab on tab.somedata = ftt.somedata
              where tab.somedata = 0 and 
                    tab.someotherdata = 1 and
                    ftt.data1 = t.data1)
```

Comment: This is a good idea and would get the job done too.  Thanks for your help.